# Selenium Python: execute code even after failure

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am using python unittest and trying to catch the exceptions. I have tried with self.fail but in that case, once there is an exception, it is a failure and it stops running the rest of the code

What can I try so even if one case fails, it still executes the rest of the cases ?

I am trying to avoid printing the exceeptions.

Code currently using:

```
if 'Anonymous' in elem_welcome.text:
    pass
else:
    self.fail('Test Failed: Logout Failed'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the try and except block and name the said 'error' on the except block
E.g. Error is 'NameError'

```
try:
  #cases
except NameError:
  #other cases
```

You can read more here [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: thank you but there are quite a few cases and a number of exception that is possible in each node so following try and except on each one would create a number of levels which I am trying to avoid. any other idea ?

Comment: I suggest you provide your code so we/others can come up with a solution specifically for your problem. This would also prevent some random solution that could confuse you. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can make every test to be a function and call it from the main block. This way each one will get executed and the failed once will return the fail reason to be filed by main block.